# ansible become_user does not take environment settings

Tags: ansible, environment

I have linux box, where there is a user "user1", using C shell. The user has .cshrc in its home directory with some useful environment settings.

when I use this ansible logic though, the environment is not set properly for the user.

```
---
- name: some playbook
  hosts: remote_host
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
    - name: Check environment variables for user1
      become: yes
      become_user: user1
      become_method: sudo 
      shell: "env"
      register: envresult

    - name: debug env
      debug:
        var: envresult.stdout
```

In the output I can see that the variables set in .cshrc are not in the environment. How can I force ansible to process the login scripts of users upon become?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `become_flags: "-i"` to your playbook. The task then looks like

```
    - name: Check environment variables for user1
      become: yes
      become_user: user1
      become_method: sudo 
      become_flags: "-i"
      shell: "env"
      register: envresult
```

More Information is available at the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/become.html#become-directives).

Comment: thank you that worked. I did read the ansible documentation but somehow slipped over it.